# Writing a variable into a container's file at a certain line

Tags: sed, configuration, variable, docker

I need to write a variable into a file which is in a docker container at line 31.
I use a bash script

my command is:

```
txt=" 
log-bin
server_id=1"
docker exec $container sed -i "31i\
$txt /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

It produce this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: extra characters after command
```

and nothing is added in my file...

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about docker containers, but if all you want is to insert the content of a variable before a certain line, you can use the following GNU sed command.

```
VAR="$txt" sed -i.bk '31{h;s:.*:printf "%s" "$VAR":e;G}' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

To be safe, the above command creates a backup of the input file with extension `.bk`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
It does not work well.

In fact it insert an empty line,

If I try with

```
VAR="$txt" 
sed -i.bk '31{h;s:.*:printf "%s" "hello world":e;G}' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

it works

If I try with

```
VAR="$txt" 
sed -i.bk '31{h;s:.*:printf "%s" "$VAR":e;G}' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

I just get a new empty line...

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait it's just a matter of " and '

This is the right syntax

```
VAR="$txt"
docker exec  $container sed -i.bk "31{h;s:.*:printf '%s' '$VAR':e;G}" $path
```

The sed command had to be quoted with double quotes "" and the intern args with single quotes '

Thanks for all mate